# Mysql Getting zero values when counting

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, count

I'm trying to count the number of sales orders has been canceled in a time period. But I run into the problem that it doesn't return results that are zero

My table

```
+---------------+------------+------------------+
| metrausername | signupdate | cancellationdate |
+---------------+------------+------------------+
| GLO00026      | 2017-06-22 | 2017-03-20       |
| GLO00055      | 2017-06-22 | 2017-04-18       |
| GLO00022      | 2017-06-27 | NULL             |
| GLO00044      | 2017-06-24 | NULL             |
| GLO00005      | 2017-06-26 | NULL             |
+---------------+------------+------------------+
```

The statment i'm trying to count with

```
SELECT metrausername, COUNT(*) AS count FROM salesdata2 
WHERE cancellationdate IS NOT NULL 
AND signupDate >= '2017-6-21' AND signupDate <= '2017-7-20' 
GROUP BY metrausername;
```

Let me know if any additional information would help

Comment: What is the data type of `signupDate`?

Comment: @Jens date, cancellationdate is date as well

Comment: can you Show the expected data? In your example only signupdates in march are visible

Comment: cancellation is not null would eliminate all metrausernames that don't have cancellations.  are you wanting to see GLO00005 in your results with a zero count? (assuming signup date is in range)

Comment: @Jens I randomly took the data from a table with over 12.000 rows, but I testet it isn't the problem

Comment: Can you try the select without Group by and Count ant take a look if you get any result?

Comment: For next time, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the metrausername is filtered out by the where, it won't appear. Left join to the aggregation to get round this:

```
select distinct a1.metrausername, coalesce(a2.counted,0) as counted -- coalesce replaces null with a value
from salesdata2  a1
left join
(
SELECT metrausername, COUNT(*) AS counted
FROM salesdata2 
WHERE cancellationdate IS NOT NULL 
AND signupDate >= '2017-6-21' AND signupDate <= '2017-7-20' 
GROUP BY metrausername
) a2
on a1.metrausername = a2.metrausername
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this return 0 instead of NULL?

Comment: There's a lot of query here.

Comment: @Strawberry Yeh, could probably be refactored somewhat

Answer (score 1):

I would just do this by moving the filtering clause to the `select`.  Assuming you really do want the date range (as opposed to having users outside the range), then:

```
SELECT metrausername, COUNT(cancellationdate ) AS count
FROM salesdata2 
WHERE signupDate >= '2017-06-21' AND signupDate <= '2017-07-20' 
GROUP BY metrausername;
```

`COUNT(<colname>)` counts the non-`NULL` values, so this seems like the simplest approach.

Comment: This won't return a `metrausername` that does not exist inside the signupdate range, which OP asked to return as 0

Comment: @JohnHC . . . I find the description confusing.  I thought the OP was simply referring to the `NULL` values that are in the range of dates.